# "cUrl call failed" using 2checkout

Tags: 2checkout

After installed the package which is downloaded from this github.

https://github.com/2checkout/2checkout-php

```
require_once("lib/Twocheckout.php");

Twocheckout::privateKey('privatekey'); //Private Key

Twocheckout::sellerId('sellerid'); // 2Checkout Account Number

// If you want to turn off SSL verification (Please don't do this in your production environment)

Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);  // this is set to true by default
// To use your sandbox account set sandbox to true
Twocheckout::sandbox(true);
// All methods return an Array by default or you can set the format to 'json' to get a JSON response.

Twocheckout::format('json');

try {
$charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
    "merchantOrderId" => "123",
    "token"      => $_POST['token'],
    "currency"   => 'USD',
    "total"      => '10.00',
    "billingAddr" => array(
        "name" => 'Joe Flagster',
        "addrLine1" => '123 Main Street',
        "city" => 'Townsville',
        "state" => 'OH',
        "zipCode" => '43206',
        "country" => 'USA',
        "email" => 'testingemail@gmail.com',
        "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
    )
));

if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') {
    echo "Thanks for your Order!";
    echo "<h3>Return Parameters:</h3>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($charge);
    echo "</pre>";

}
} catch (Twocheckout_Error $e) {
print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

After submitting the form using sandbox mode it shows the error like "cUrl call failed". How to fix this one

Answer (score 4):

Adding below line

```
Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);
```

Comment: This is not at all clear and has been flagged for review. *Where* would you add the line? *What* does it do to improve the code?

Comment: Add this line any where after require statement and before try block.

Comment: This works. Remember to re-enable SSL when necessary too.

Answer (score 1):

If we set the username and password for the twocheckout it will work fine.

Add this line below this line:

```
require_once("lib/Twocheckout.php");

// Your username and password are required to make any Admin API call.
Twocheckout::username('username');
Twocheckout::password('password');
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2Checkout sandbox only supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2 protocols. This library should have no issues supporting those protocols. Can you check what version of `PHP` and `OpenSSL` you are running?
`php -v` and `openssl version`

OpenSSL added support for TLS v1.1 & TLS v1.2 in v1.0.1.
Major changes between OpenSSL 1.0.0h and OpenSSL 1.0.1

thx : [craigchristenson](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-php/issues/15)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Wamp64. This error for me was resolved when I added apache->modules->ssl. Altough I did

```
Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);
```

but didn't work out without enabling ssl.